# Reading data from a text file using Strpos & Substr to remove commas between and a while loop to repeat for each row

Tags: php

I'll try and be as clear as I can with what my problem is here, I've been working on this one for a while now and can't seem to get my head around it. Basically, I'm trying to:

Read numbers from a text file & store them in a 2D array

Remove any commas in the text file and store the remaining data in a table format

Using strpos & substr to extract the data, leaving behind unwanted commas

Then using a while loop to repeat this process so every line in the text file is read one at a time until all the lines are read. 
 
At first my code was stating what lines I had errors in and I have since amended but now the php page doesnt seem to load at all. Is there some sort of error within my while loop statement?

Here is the php code I'm currently working with that doesnt seem to be loading:

```
$fileopen = fopen($file,'r') or die("Sorry, cannot find the file $file");
if($fileopen){
    while (($buffer=fgets($fileopen,4096))!==false){
    }    
    if(!feof($fileopen)){
        echo "Error:unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }    
    fclose($fileopen);    
}

$filearray = array();

$rows = 0;
$columns = 0;

$fileopen = fopen($file,'r') or die("Sorry, cannot open $file");
while(!feof($fileopen))
{

    $line = fgets($fileopen);
    $length = strlen($line); 
    $pos = 0;
    $comma = 0;

    while($pos < length) {
        $comma = strpos($line,",",$comma);
        $filearray[$rows][$columns] = substr($line,$pos,$comma);
        $pos = $comma +1;
        $columns++;
    }
    $columns = 0;
    $rows++;
}
```

This section is essentially displaying the extracted data from the text file in a table format:

```
function array_transpose($filearray)
{
    array_unshift($filearray, NULL);
    return call_user_func_array('array_map', $filearray);
}

echo"<h1></h1>";

echo "<table border = 0 >";
for($row=0; $row<$count; $row++){
    print "<tr>";
    for($col=0; $col<$count; $col++){
        echo "<td>".$array[$row][$col]."</td>";
    } 
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Could you please post the text file, you may be able to make use of the `explode` function.

Comment: Why the jquery tag?

Comment: Please clerify your question. _store the remaining data in a table format_ - What table format? _Remove any commas in the text file_ -> _leaving behind unwanted commas_ <- This makes no sense. You're talking about extracting data. What data? Read numbers and put them in a 2D array. What numbers? 28 can be 2 and 8 or just 28. But what 2D array? How should it look like?

Comment: Yes sorry, I have a text file containing single and double digit numbers. These numbers are separated by commas, for example row 1 consists of 25, 3, 41, 61, 16, 4, 92, 51
I'm looking to extract all numbers from the text file and remove any commas, leaving me with just the numbers

Comment: Ok. So just to be clear: You have text file with just numbers and commas on seperate rows? And if so, you want a 2D array with basicly all the numbers from every row in seperate keys?

Comment: Yes thats correct

Comment: You have a csv file. Sounds like you just need [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: So post an example of the text file so we can see it

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Seems like this is what you want: http://viper-7.com/dexZ1o ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/8LBTS Here is what my text file looks like.
Apologies for the lack of code indentation, it's my first time posting to Stack Overflow. I have proper code indentation in Brackets

Comment: Thanks that reply icecub! Unfortunately I can't use explode for this project. I can only use strpos and substr for extracting each number by removing “,” each time

Comment: Why can't you use `explode()`? It sounds to me like this is a school assignment..

Comment: It's a project yes. I'm not expecting this done for me I can assure you. I'm thinking there is something not right with my while loop statements and I'm simply asking for help from an extra set of eyes thats all.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking about school projects. But please follow the guidelines about those: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). We can't help you exactly the way you want to if we don't fully understand the assignment.

Comment: Thanks for that link, I checked it out. I genuinely have made an attempt at this one. Thats one reason why I supplied my code up front. I'm completely stumped on this one. Basically we have been asked to read all the numbers in the txt file by using fgets and use array to store the numbers. I am only allowed to use strpos and substr for extracting each number by removing “,” each time and I cannot use explode or any other functions.. I've managed to get the numbers read in successfully but I'm having trouble removing the commas

Comment: Now that's making a LOT more sense! If you only you would've put that into your question from the start, we could've helped you out a lot faster :) I would suggest you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47584385/edit) your question and clearly explain that in there. Make it clear it's a school assigment and explain what you've tried and where you got stuck. Just like you did here.

Comment: Will do! Sorry for the confusion! Its getting real late and I have literally been working on this work over a week now and I feel like I'm making no progress at this point

Comment: It's fine. You're new to Stack Overflow and don't fully understand how it works yet. You're allowed to make mistakes ;) By showing what you've already tried yourself you've actually done yourself a huge favor. If you didn't, your question would've been closed very fast and no one would even bother to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Well yea it wouldnt benefit me in the long run if i just asked for code. I've been running through a php codecademy course in my spare time too but any examples I have come across have used the explode function. I can see how it works and perhaps is probably the most efficient way but obviously, there is some way of doing this using strpos and substr

Comment: Of course there is. Now that I actually understand what's required, I can work on an answer that you need and teach you where you went wrong and why. May take some time though. I've never done it with the functions you're allowed to use, so I have to test it myself as well. So unless someone else answers faster, I should come up with something

Comment: That's fine mate I appreciate any help at all. Yes given my restrictions in functions it has been rather difficult. As I said I have seen the explode function in use before and it does seem more effective but if you are able to come up with some sample code for me to check out that would be fantastic

Comment: sorry i dont know what exactly your trouble/ problem?

Comment: Scarlet witch when I hit submit on my html page the php page doesn’t seem to load at all

Comment: Well at least I've already found your problem. You are using the string length with `$pos`. The problem is that `$pos` no longer gets increased when there are no more commas. Resulting in `$pos` always being smaller than the string length. This causes an infinite loop. Hence the file doesnt load.

Comment: Why do you insist on using string manipulation functions for a file that is likely in the standard CSV format? Use a standard parser.

Answer (score 1):

It was quite the challenge for me to get this one to work, but I managed to do it. I've put comments inside the code to explain what's happening. The reasons it didn't work for you (as I said in the comments) was because you were creating an infinite loop. The `$pos` integer was always smaller than your `$length` integer. So the `while()` loop would never break.

Another issue that you didn't encounter yet was the use of `$comma` as the length for `substr()`. Because `strpos()` returns you the actual position and not the position relative to the offset, this would cause problems. That's why you needed to save the previous position of the delimiter (comma) and substract that from the current position of the delimiter.

Anyway, here is my example code. It's giving you the result that you need. It's up to you to incorporate it into your own code.

```
<?php

// Initial variables
$result = array();
$key = 0;

// Open the file
$handle = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");

if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // First we set the delimiter into a variable
        $delimiter = ',';

        // Some integers we're going to use for our loop
        $pos = 0;       // The current position
        $comma = 0;     // Position of the next comma
        $innerkey = 0;  // Key used for the 2D result array
        $previous = 0;  // Previous comma position
        $loops = 0;     // Number of loops
        $nr_commas = substr_count($line, $delimiter); // Number of commas in a single line

        while($loops <= $nr_commas) {
            // Get the position of the next comma
            $comma = strpos($line,$delimiter,$comma);

            // Make sure a comma is found
            if($comma !== false){
                // Put the substring into the result array using $pos as the offset
                // and calculating the length by substracting the position of the previous
                // comma from the current comma.
                $result[$key][$innerkey] = substr($line,$pos,$comma - $previous);

                // Add 1 to the previous comma or it will include the current comma in the result
                $previous = $comma + 1;
                $pos = $comma + 1;
                $innerkey++;
                $loops++;
                $comma++;
            } else {
                // In case no more commas are found, we still need to add the last integer
                $loops++;
                $result[$key][$innerkey] = substr($line,strrpos($line,$delimiter)+1);
            }
        }
        $key++;
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo "Unable to open the file";
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

**TXT File used:**

```
3,34,2,35,4,234,34,2,53,4
5,4,23,6,67,324,5,34,5
345,67,3,45,6,7
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 34
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 35
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 234
            [6] => 34
            [7] => 2
            [8] => 53
            [9] => 4

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 23
            [3] => 6
            [4] => 67
            [5] => 324
            [6] => 5
            [7] => 34
            [8] => 5

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 345
            [1] => 67
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 45
            [4] => 6
            [5] => 7
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this mate. Reading over it there this morning it makes a lot of sense. I’m going to have another go at this again this morning when I’m free!